# Shortcode displaying strangely

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, shortcode

I'm trying to get a shortcode to add an id to a div, and that part works fine, but it adds some extra stuff and I'm not sure if it's because I did something wrong, or if it's something else.  Here is the actual shortcode:

```
function jump_function($params){
    //Extract parameters and supply default values
    extract( shortcode_atts( array(
        'id' => ''
    ), $params ) );

    //The parameters are now stored as variables
    return do_shortcode('<div id="' . $id . '"</div>');
}
add_shortcode( 'jump', 'jump_function' );
```

I'm trying to get it to display as

```
<div id="id-here"></div>
```

but on the page it's displaying as this:

```
<div div="" <="" id="id-here" style="position: relative;"><div></div></div>
```

Did I do anything wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`do_shortcode` doesn't work like this...
you don't need it.

```
function jump_function($params){
    //Extract parameters and supply default values
    extract( shortcode_atts( array(
        'id' => ''
    ), $params ) );

    //The parameters are now stored as variables
    return '<div id="' . $id . '"</div>';
}
add_shortcode( 'jump', 'jump_function' );
```

http://codex.wordpress.org/do_shortcode